# Use javah to generate header file

Tags: java, c++, javah

i am triyng to generate header file for native use (c/c++) from a java file using eclipse.
from the command line i can only reach the javah when i am in this location :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin>
```

but i cant reference my java class like so :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin>javah -jni com.or.jnihelloworld.nativeclass
```

because the class located outside of this folder at :

```
C:\Users\Or Azran\workspace\JniHelloWorld\src\NativeLib.java
```

and i want to make this file in to a jni folder in :

```
C:\Users\Or Azran\workspace\JniHelloWorld\jni
```

how can i do it from command line?
a good toturial will be also great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There appears to be a couple of issues to solve here.

First.  I'm not sure that your source code is set up correctly.  If indeed your class is com.or.jnihelloworld.nativeclass  then it should be in directory: C:\Users\Or Azran\workspace\JniHelloWorld\src\com\or\jnihelloworld\nativeclass.java

However, assuming that the class/directory is correct.  The javah command uses -d to specify the output directory, and you can specify the path with -classpath so

```
javah -classpath "C:\Users\Or Azran\workspace\JniHelloWorld\src\" \ 
-d "C:\Users\Or Azran\workspace\JniHelloWorld\jni" com.or.jnihelloworld.nativeclass
```

should put the file where you want it.

Comment: it dosent work with your example like this :  javah -classpath "c:\Users\Or Azran\
workspace\JniHelloWorld\src\" \ -d "c:\Users\Or Azran\workspace\JniHelloWorld\jn
i" com.or.jnihelloworld.jnilib.java

Comment: Well the extra slash before the  -d indicated it shoudl be one line I broke it into two for readability.

Comment: when i am calling this : javah -classpath "C:\Users\Or\workspace\NativeCodeTest\src\com\infinityar\nativecodetest\" -d "C:\Users\Or\workspace\NativeCodeTest\jni" com.infinityar.nativecodetest.NativeLib
 i get "ERROR: no classes specified"

Comment: You have compiled your java file first?

Comment: it makes automatic build so i think i do

Comment: In which case the class path will need to find the .class file.

Answer (score 1):

Your PATH doesn't include the bin directory of the JDK.

Comment: Err, fix your PATH so it does?